# Pointer Based Bubble Sort in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

Ive been trying to get the code to sort an user inputted array using a pointer based bubble sort in C++. The code compiles without error, but the array doesn't get sorted. Pointers have never been my strong area and I cant get them to work correctly. Heres my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int *ptr = &i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        if (*(ptr + j) > *(ptr + j + 1))
        {
            int temp = *(ptr + j);
            *(ptr + j) = *(ptr + j + 1);
            *(ptr + j + 1) = temp;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: it's been a long time since I read C++ code, but you might try changing your pointer int *ptr = &i; to point to the start of the array arr[0] since otherwise I think you're just pointing to the memory address of i which won't help you reorder the nodes in arr[]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 mistakes:

1. As mentioned by @Lukasz P. in the comment, `int* ptr` should point to the array `arr`, `int* ptr = arr;`
2. You access out of bounds for the last element (when `j = 8`)
3. You need to keep sorting until there are no more swaps:

   ```
   bool sorted = false; // keep track here whether you still need to sort
   int *ptr = arr;
   while (!sorted) // repeat this until no more swaps
   {
       sorted = true;
       for (int j = 0; j < 8 ; j++) // Repeat until N - 1 (i.e. 8 in this case)
       {
           if (*(ptr + j ) > *(ptr + j + 1)) // make sure you don't access out of bounds
           {
               int temp = *(ptr + j);
               *(ptr + j) = *(ptr + j + 1);
               *(ptr + j + 1) = temp;
               sorted = false; // we swapped, so keep sorting
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I think there is an inefficiency here; you shouldn't have the `break;` (plus other changes). If you consider the array [9, 1, 2, 3, 4]. After 9 has been moved once, you check if 1 > {2,9} 3 times when this check has already been done. I think the idea is to pass through the whole array in every while loop. That way any "bubbles" propagate to the top (or bottom) in a single pass. Also the array should be considered sorted at the start of each for loop until there is a swap.

Comment: @racitup Forgot my BubbleSort :) Changed.